# Generating new fields with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to generate a new form when an item is pushed into an array. 
The form is always the same, it just increases by one the conditional count.

Something like this:

```
<span ng-show="companydata.selectedloc.length == 0">
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
    selected-object="selectedLocation"
    ></div>
</span>

<span ng-show="companydata.selectedloc.length == 1">
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
    selected-object="selectedLocation"
    ></div>
</span>

<span ng-show="companydata.selectedloc.length == 2">
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
    selected-object="selectedLocation"
    ></div>
</span>
```

Every code block pushes an item into **companydata.selectedloc** on select (it's an autocomplete select input).

Here's the JS function:

```
$scope.selectedLocation = function(selected){
    $scope.companydata.selectedloc.push(selected)
}
```

Being always the same code block, is there some way more elegant to do that than increasing the condition manually and adding as many code blocks as necessary (let's say to a max of 10)?

Comment: Meet your friend `ng-repeat`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @cale_b I worked with ng-repeat, but how do ng-repeat a code block as many times as objects in an unrelated array?

Comment: Not sure I understand how it's "unrelated" - you have a direct correlation between `companydata.selectedloc` and the number of inputs, so they seem highly related.  The guts of the ng-repeat html do NOT have to pertain to the item that is being repeated over, so based on your html exaple, it would be very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of Angular's built-in [ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Here's a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/qn167ry8/)

Note that in the fiddle, I added `track by $index`, since I don't know what your `selected` values are.  Note that track by $index has tradeoffs, but is sometimes required to prevent dupes errors being thrown by Angular.

From the fiddle, I declared the `companydata` variable like so:

```
$scope.companydata = {
  selectedloc: [] // Initialized with an empty array
}
```

If you want it to be pre-populated, that's simple enough:

```
$scope.companydata = {
  selectedloc: [0, 1, 2] // Initialized with valu(es) as needed
}
```

See this [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/qn167ry8/3/) for a richer example where I've updated it with simulated "location" objects.

```
<span ng-repeat="loc in companydata.selectedloc">
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
    selected-object="selectedLocation"
    ></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Any way to show one element by default without having to duplicate the form? The array is empty on load, but it should already show one code block (at it contains the input to add objects)